# How can I put a a gradient text on a btn in Safari?

Tags: css, button, transparent, linear-gradients, rgba

The gradient works in Chrome but not Safari. I'm aware the browsers render transparent in different ways, but still can't figure it out.
I have tried:

```
transparent ,rgba(255,255,255,0), and white
```

still no luck. Here is what I currently have :

```
.btn{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #fdb813 0%, #788cb6 74%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0);}

.btn:hover{  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(319deg, #fce055 0%, #256eff 37%, #46237a 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

[Chrome button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFYop.png)

[Safari button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6YCm.png)

Also, the gradient work with text outside of the btn.
[Non button gradient in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLzv3.png)

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like this is just a bug with buttons. I've been trying to crack it for a little bit.

That said, if those buttons are linking out to other sites, apps, or pages, it's probably better semantically for them to be anchor tags instead of buttons. There is no issue getting that gradient text with an `<a>`.

Comment: I confirm. With <a> text gradient works like a charm.